# CodeIgniter - Upload file using a form

Tags: php, html, frameworks, codeigniter-3

I am a bit desperate already, because I am programming a project in CodeIgniter which is an Online store of food products. The problem is that when I have to create the product, I have a form in which the administrator is asked to enter, the name, brand, description, price, VAT, category, etc. of the product, and in between, there is another field that is the **product image**. Well, when I fill in that form and submit it, the product is added to the database and everything works great, except that the product image **is not copied** from my hard drive to the server folder.

I'm using:
  PHP 7.3.9
  MySQL 5.7.26
  CodeIgniter 3.1.8

I put the code of this form (the view), which I have already changed so many times, that there must be errors excessively:

```
<div class="container">
<?php if (isset($error)) {?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <?php echo validation_errors('<div class="container"><b><ul><li>','</li></ul></b></div>') ?>
    </div>
<?php }?>       
<div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-body">
        <h3 style='margin-left: 4em'>Crear Producto</h3>
        <h6 style='margin-left: 8em'>Rellena los siguientes campos con los datos del producto y una vez termines pulsa el botón.</h6>
        <hr>
        <?php echo form_open_multipart('Inicio/verificarProducto'); ?>
        <div class="row">

            <div style='margin-left: 6em' class="container">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="user">Nombre *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?=set_value('nombre')?>" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre del Producto" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pass">Descripción *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="descripcion" value="<?=set_value('descripcion')?>" class="form-control" id="descripcion" placeholder="Descripción del Producto" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><hr>

            <div style='margin-left: 6em' class="container">

                <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="image">Imagen *</label>

                            <!--El name del campo tiene que ser si o si "userfile"-->
                            <input type="file" name="imagen" value="<?=set_value('imagen')?>" />



                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="marca">Marca *</label>
                            <input type="text" name="marca" value="<?=set_value('marca')?>" class="form-control" id="marca" placeholder="Marca del Producto" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pvp">PVP *</label>
                            <input type="numeric" name="pvp" value="<?=set_value('pvp')?>" class="form-control" id="pvp" placeholder="0" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="iva">IVA *</label>
                            <input type="number" step=".01" name="iva" value="<?=set_value('iva')?>" class="form-control" id="iva" placeholder="0" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><h6 style='color: #2874A6;'>*El IVA no puede ser negativo.</h6>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2"><hr>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="stock">Stock *</label>
                            <input type="number" name="stock" value="<?=set_value('stock')?>" class="form-control" id="stock" placeholder="0" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="categoria">Categoria *</label>
                            <input type="text" name="categoria" value="<?=set_value('categoria')?>" class="form-control" id="categoria" placeholder="Categoria del Producto" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="finicio_dest">Fecha inicio de destacado (opcional)</label>
                            <input type="date" name="finicio_dest" value="<?=set_value('finicio_dest')?>" class="form-control" id="finicio_dest">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="ffin_dest">Fecha final de destacado (opcional)</label>
                            <input type="date" name="ffin_dest" value="<?=set_value('ffin_dest')?>" class="form-control" id="ffin_dest">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  

            <hr>
            <a class="btn btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 50px;" href="<?=site_url().'/Inicio/cargarVista/panel_usuario_admin'?>"><b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Volver atrás</b></a></center><button style='margin-left: 7em' type="submit" name="bcontinuar" class="btn btn-success"><B>Finalizar</B>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button><br>
        </div>
    <?php echo form_close() ?>
</div>
```

Here is the fragment of the controller in charge of the form:

```
public function verificarProducto()
{
  $prueba = $this->mproducto->verCategoriasEx($this->input->post('category'));

  if($this->mproducto->verCategoriasEx($this->input->post('category')) >= 0){
    $a = intval($this->mproducto->verCategoriasEx($this->input->post('category')));
  }else{
    $datos_cat = array(
      'name' => $this->input->post('category'),
      'description' => "",
      'announce' => 0,
      'show' => 1
    );

    $a = $this->mproducto->insertaCategoria($datos_cat);
  }


  $datos = array(
    'category_id' => $a ,
    'name' => $this->input->post('nombre'),
    'brand' => $this->input->post('marca'),
    'description' => $this->input->post('descripcion'),
    'discount' => 0,
    'announce' => 0,
    'image' => $this->input->post('image'),
    'pvp' => $this->input->post('pvp'),
    'iva' => $this->input->post('iva'),
    'stock' => $this->input->post('stock'),
    'show' => 1,
    'finicio_dest' => $this->input->post('finicio_dest'),
    'ffin_dest' => $this->input->post('ffin_dest'),
    'destacado' => 1
  );
  $this->mproducto->insertaProducto($datos);
  $cuerpo = $this->load->view("producto_creado", "", TRUE);
  $this->cargaPlantilla($cuerpo, "");
}
```

Here is the fragment of the controller that upload the image:

```
<?php
if(!defined('BASEPATH'))
  exit('No direct script access allowed');

class subir_controller extends CI_Controller {

 public function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
}

public function index(){ 
  $this->load->view('nuevoProducto', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

public function subir(){
  $dato = $this->input->post("txt_dato");
  $image_name = $_FILES['archivoImagen']['name'];
  $data = array("dato" => $dato, "image" => $image_name);
  $guardar = $this->msubir->guardar($data);
  $this->subirImagen();
}   

public function subirImagen(){
  $nombreCompleto = $_FILES['archivoImagen']['name'];
  $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/productos/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
  $config['file_name'] = $nombreCompleto;
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

  if(!$this->upload->do_upload('archivoImagen')) {
    $data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
  } else {
    $data['infoImagen'] = $this->upload->data();
  }
}
}
?>
```

And finally, the model here:

```
<?php
class Subir_model extends CI_Model
{
    function guardar($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert("subir", $data);
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have been trying things for a long time and surely from the mixture of solutions that I have tried, there is something about the code that does not make much sense, but right now, it works as I told you at the top of the question. Save **all** data, including image name, to the database, but **don't** copy the image to the server folder.

If you don't understand something, please, let me know and I try to answer you as soon al possible.

I appreciate your help in advance.

var_dump($_POST) prints:

```
array(10) { ["nombre"]=> string(4) "test" ["descripcion"]=> string(4) "test" ["marca"]=> string(4) "test" ["pvp"]=> string(2) "10" ["iva"]=> string(2) "10" ["stock"]=> string(3) "100" ["categoria"]=> string(4) "Test" ["finicio_dest"]=> string(0) "" ["ffin_dest"]=> string(0) "" ["bcontinuar"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to use the "form_open_multipart" function for the form opener as it allows uploading files. Otherwise it sends only the text.

> This function is identical to form_open() above, except that it adds a
>   multipart attribute, which is necessary if you would like to use the
>   form to upload files with.

I can see you are having 2 forms nested, which is not good idea. You should remove the nested form.
In that case that field could not be retrieved from the main form and returns NULL. Otherwise if image is not selected it would simply return empty string.

Also it is a good idea to turn on the XSS FILTER to protect the data entered through the form by using the TRUE tag in input->post function like this:

```
$this->input->post('some_data', TRUE);
```

That would escape the string and prevent xss attacks.

Comment: If I use  "form_open_multipart", when I submit the form, I receive a Database Error, because the image column cannot be null and the form is sending it as null :(

Comment: I see that you have form inside that form. That is not a good solution. I would suggest removing the "<form action="subir">". If the image input is present it would return empty string and not NULL.

Comment: I have removed it but it still not working. I receive the same error. The image column is NULL not empty...

Comment: Could you remove the "action" and "method" on the input field as well? I mean this one:
<input type="file" name="image" action="<?=base_url("subir_controller/subir")?>" method="post" value="<?=set_value('image')?>" />

Comment: The same.. Action and method removed and I receive the same database error with null image... :(

Comment: Could you update the code in the question? There seems to be other issues with your html code. Otherwise it should be working.
Also if you are still having double </form> please remove one of them

Comment: I can upload the full code to a GitHub project as well if you want to see all the code updated. I'm going to update the code on that question too.

Comment: Hey, I see now that your "image" field has name "imageN" is that the issue? Looks like the name is with added "N" in the end that is missing in the controller.

Comment: I have translated some variables only for this question, but in my controller, the field is "imagen"... sorry for the confusion...

Comment: If you send me your email, I can invite you to the GitHub project and you can see all the code.

Comment: thank you very much! I have sent you the invitation ^^

Comment: Found something??

Comment: @FlavioGarcía I don't see an issue with the code anymore. There is just a label showing for "image" instead of "imagen", which is not a big issue.

Maybe try with smaller image or different format. Usually servers are blocking images bigger than 2MB or so. If the upload is working when you select small image, you can just prevent it from sending null by adding 'imagen' => (($this->input->post('imagen',TRUE)) ? $this->input->post('imagen', TRUE) : '')

Comment: The image size is not the problem, I'm trying to submit a png image of 98kb... but the form does not return any image... it's so strange... :(

Comment: Are the other fields sent correctly? Are you sure you have uploaded the latest files?

Could you do var_dump($_POST); to see what is in there?
Could you change the name of the input in case something is duplicating with that name and try again.

Comment: var_dump($_POST) prints that: (EDIT AT THE QUESTION)

Image is not in there.. :S I have uploaded the latest files to GitHub All the fields are sent ok, but the image is not...